# Printing a string backwards in C with scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to print my string backwards in c and I just can't seem to get it working with whitespaces. I am aware that if there is any whitespace after the last returned character in the scanf function that it will terminate because there is no existing characters left to scan in from the string entered. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLETTERS 20

void readStringBackwards();

main()
{
readStringBackwards();
}


void readStringBackwards()
{



printf("Please enter a string of up to 20 characters in length:\n ");
char str[20];
scanf("%s", str);
int i;
int stringlength = strlen(str);

if (stringlength > MAXLETTERS)
{
    printf("The string length is too long!");
}
else
{
    for( i = stringlength-1; i >= 0; i--){

        printf("%c ", str[i]);

    }

}



}
```

Essentially the program is supposed to accept up to 20 characters, and print the string backwards. I have been searching for information on scanf and how it works, but its been pretty hard to find a direct answer. Any tips are appreciated. Right now all I will get is the first word that I type in reverse. The other characters after an space are skipped and not stored within the array.

Comment: If the user enters > MAXLETTERS then you simply have a buffer overflow.  You cannot reliably call strlen to figure out if they did or not, it's already too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%s", str);` will read up to a whitespace, even if its more than 20 chars. Blank, newline and tab are considered whitespace characters.

Consider using a format specification like `"%20[^\n]"`, that should be read up to 20 chars as long as they are not `'\n'`.

**edit:** As Oli Charlesworth pointed out, the buffer would have to be at least length 21, not 20.

Comment: @Oli: Maybe, yet he still says he wants to read after whitespace.

Comment: This is perfect for what I wanted it to do. thank you! I don't know all the format specifications, is there is a reference I can use to learn them?

Comment: @TMGunter: Note also that your buffer *must* be length 21, not 20.

Comment: Yes, google for "printf format specification". Note that my format specifier won't read the trailing '\n', which could give trouble in subsequent reads. Add `\n` again at the end, so that the new-line character is consumed.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`fgets()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) instead of `scanf()`?

```
char str[21]; // Note 21, not 20 (remember the null terminator)
fgets(stdin, 21, str);
```

Note that if the string is less than 20 characters, you'll get the newline character included, so you'll need to remove that (overwriting with `'\0'` is fine).

Comment: I was trying to not use "gets". I've been reading up around the net and it seems like everyone says not to use it. Why do they say that though?

Comment: @TMGunter: `fgets` isn't the same as `gets`.  They tell you not to use `gets` because it has no way to specify the length of the receiving buffer.  So if the user types in more than 20 characters, it'll overwrite something on your stack.

Comment: @TMGunter That't about `gets`. `gets` is a bad function because it doesn't limit the number of characters entered. It would be used as `gets(str);` and you could have a possible buffer overflow. `fgets` function, on the other side, is a nice, good function :D (the second argument tells the max number of characters to be read)

Answer (score -1):

This code is working perfectly but try using `gets()` instead of `scanf()` to read spaces in string!